# Separating business logic and model

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, separation-of-concerns

I have this question that's been bothering me for a while now. At first glance it might seem like a fairly basic question, but there doesn't seem to be a clear answer. My basis for asking this question is a Python project that uses PostgreSQL through SQLAlchemy, but the specific language and tools used don't really matter.

The basic question is where to put logic when using an ORM? More concretely, what logic should go into methods of my mapping classes?

There seem to be some clear-cut cases, for instance, basic validation of properties, such as minimum length or whether or not something is an email address should belong in the ORM layer (or even in the database itself.)

A simple concrete example is in order, so lets assume we are storing User objects, Users have an  email-address (which is their unique id), a password and an activation id. When an account is created an activation id is assigned and mailed to the user, which she then uses to set a password.

Let's look at a couple of scenarios:

- User creates an account;
- User activates account (i.e. sets a password).

So when the user creates the account we need to run some basic validation:

- Email address correct => ORM;
- Email address unique => ORM or Database (unique constraint);
- Set a random activation id => ORM

When the user activates her account I run into problems. I would want to validate the supplied password (e.g. long enough? Enough digits?), but the model should stores the password using some sort of hashing or encryption algorithm. There seem to be two options:

1: Check activation id, and password validity outside of the model, hash the password then set the User.password to the hash, and User.activation id to null (to signal an active account).

2: Create a User.activate(activation_id, password) method that validates everyting and sets the User.password and User.activation_id properties accordingly.

3: Hybrid option, do option 1, but have some sort of hook or event set the activation_id = null when the password gets set, (if we assume either activation id or password can be set, then this hook satisfies a basic consistency property of the model).

I've searched on the internet and there are some sources that talk about this problem (including some SO questions,) but none really answer the question.

Comment: Model layer in MVC contains the domain business logic. I suspect that you for some reason assume that "models" are classes/objects.

Comment: I've gone to what I believe is two extremes: trying to stuff all the logic into the ORM-mapped classes, or keeping the ORM-mapped classes simply data and putting the logic elsewhere. My conclusion: it doesn't matter where you put the logic, it's all going to become a mess in the end.

Comment: The "business logic" goes in the [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject), "persistence logic" - in storage abstractions (the optimal solution would be cusomt made [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) but some newbies prefers ORM magic) and the interaction between domain objects and storage abstractions is called *"application logic", which gose in the services. These three groups combined constitute **model layer**. Problem is that people look at Rails, and think that it is MVC. **Rails is not MVC**. Neither are frameworks that mimic it.

Comment: "the optimal solution would be...".. citation? I'm voting to close the question, since I don't think there is any way this can be objectively answered. Perhaps this is better on [the programmers stackexchange](https://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @tereško If you have a good reference URL in mind for the model layer you describe, I'd be interested.

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys actually the best source would be http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html book.

Comment: The [Cosmic Python](https://www.cosmicpython.com) book discusses this at length.

Comment: @snakecharmerb. I love how it starts: "In the book we are at pains to point out that each pattern is a trade-off, and comes with costs. But just on the offchance that anyone was still missing the message and thinking we were saying that all apps should be built like this, I thought I’d write a small blog post just to reinforce the message about costs. If you’ve been feeling tempted to cargo-cult every single pattern into every single app from now on, this should put you off."